# Glassfish UnsupportedClassVersionError Class org.json.JSONArray

Tags: java, glassfish, org.json

My web application deployment on GlassFish fails after adding and using org.json dependency to POM, it was working properly before!

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20141113</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

error stack in GlassFish Server log

```
Severe:   WebModule[/qtiweb]Servlet /qtiweb threw load() exception
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Class org.json.JSONArray has unsupported major or minor version numbers, which are greater than those found in the Java Runtime Environment version 1.7.0_80
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.findClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1239)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1750)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1633)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1868)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:571)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:488)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:474)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:241)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1065)
    ...
    ...
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```